# Flutter: How to implement different screencast orientations to TV on both Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-cast, screencast

I am looking to do a flutter app that is locked into Portrait mode. It will need to play a video and also use the camera in half screens as a stack with various graphical outputs layered on top of the video and cameraview.
What I am looking to accomplish is when connected to a secondary device such as a TV, I want to be able to display a different orientation of the same Video stack, but rearranged in landscape mode. Would this be possible?
I know there are solutions for this such as Android Multiwindow or iOS UIWindowScene, but I was looking for a solution for this directly in Flutter without having to go the channels route. I am also wondering if there is a preferred video player for this type of solution as well.

Thank you.

I was not able to find a solution to this so far though I have tried multiple screencast solutions that were a direct mirror of the mobile device.